# Usecase of Variants in Purescript/Haskell

Tags: functional-programming, variant, purescript

Can someone tell me what is the use case of [purescript-variants](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-variant/7.0.1/docs/Data.Variant) or variants in general

The documentation is very well written but I can't find any real use case scenario for it. Can someone tell how we could use Variants in real world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variants are duals of records. While records are sort of extensible ad-hoc product types (consider `data T = T Int String` vs. `type T = { i :: Int, s :: String }`), variants can be seen as extensible ad-hoc sum types - e.g. `data T = A Int | B String` vs. `Variant (a :: Int, b :: String)`

For example, just as you can write a function that handles a partial record:

```hs
fullName :: forall r. { first :: String, last :: String | r } -> String
fullName r = r.first <> " " <> r.last

myFullName = fullName { first: "Fyodor", last: "Soikin", weight: "Too much" }
```

so too, you can write a function that handles a partial variant:

```hs
weight :: forall r. Variant (kilos :: Int, vague :: String | r) -> String
weight = 
  default "Unknown"
  # on _kilos (\n -> show n <> " kg.")
  # on _vague (\s -> "Kind of a " <> s)

myWeight = weight (inj _kilos 100)  -- "100 kg."

alsoMyWeight = weight (inj _vague "buttload")  -- "Kind of a buttload"
```

But these are, of course, toy examples. For a less toy example, I would imagine something that handles alternatives, but needs to be extensible. Perhaps something like a file parser:

```hs
data FileType a = Json | Xml

basicParser :: forall a. FileType a -> String -> Maybe a
basicParser t contents = case t of
  Json -> parseJson contents
  Xml -> parseXml contents
```

Say I'm ok using this parser in most case, but in some cases I'd also like to be able to parse YAML. What do I do? I can't "extend" the `FileType` sum type post-factum, the best I can do is aggregate it in a larger type:

```hs
data BetterFileType a = BasicType (FileType a) | Yaml

betterParser :: forall a. BetterFileType a -> String -> Maybe a
betterParser t contents = case t of
  BasicType bt -> basicParser bt contents
  Yaml -> parseYaml contents
```

And now whenever I call the "better parser", I have to wrap the file type awkwardly:

```hs
result = betterParser (BasicType Json) "[1,2,3]"
```

Worse: now every consumer has to know the hierarchy of `BetterFileType` -> `FileType`, they can't just say "json", they have to know to wrap it in `BasicType`. Awkward.

But if I used extensible variants for the file type, I could have flattened them nicely:

```hs
type FileType r = (json :: String, xml :: String | r)

basicParser :: forall a r. Variant (FileType r) -> Maybe a
basicParser = onMatch { json: parseJson, xml: parseXml } $ default Nothing
----
type BetterFileType r = (yaml :: String | FileType r)

betterParser :: forall a r. Variant (BetterFileType r) -> Maybe a
betterParser = onMatch { yaml: parseYaml } basicParser
```

Now I can use the naked variant names with either `basicParser` or `betterParser`, without knowing to wrap them or not:

```hs
r1 = betterParser $ inj _json "[1,2,3]"
r2 = betterParser $ inj _yaml "foo: [1,2,3]"
```